# Flaky JavaFX ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID MediaException

Tags: java, exception, javafx, media-player

I wrote a JavaFX based application (Java: 18.0.2, Oracle Corporation and
JavaFX: 19+11, Win 11) to guide through sport training sessions by showing short movies with the respective exercises. For testing purposes I created the first 4 short movies, which I really want to use, once the application is stable.
The issue is that over 90% of the time the application throws

```
MediaException: UNKNOWN : [com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@3f239193] ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID: ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
    at javafx.media@19/javafx.scene.media.MediaException.getMediaException(MediaException.java:161)
    at javafx.media@19/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$_MediaErrorListener.onError(MediaPlayer.java:2624)
    at javafx.media@19/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.HandleErrorEvents(NativeMediaPlayer.java:692)
    at javafx.media@19/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.run(NativeMediaPlayer.java:426)
```

on one of the four movies. Which movie triggers the exception differs. While the earlier JavaFX version stumbled frequently over the first movie as well, since I installed the current JavaFX version the first movie most of the time - not always - runs fine.

I checked the release notes and I took from it, that unusual width and height may cause a problem. However, I would expect that either the movie can be shown or not. But that the application sometimes shows the movies and sometimes not, makes it difficult to address the issue.

Following some info about the four movies:

```
All of the videos are 
   - Format                               : MPEG-4 
   - Format-Profil                        : Base Media / Version 2 
   - Codec-ID                             : mp42 (mp41/isom)
   - ID                                   : 1 
     - Format                             : AVC 
     - Format/Info                        : Advanced Video Codec
     - Format-Profil                      : Baseline@L3.1
     - Format-Setting                     : 2 Ref Frames
     - Format-Setting for CABAC           : No 
     - Format-Setting for RefFrames       : 2 frames 
     - Codec-ID                           : avc1 
     - Codec-ID/Info                      : Advanced Video Coding 
     - Aspect ratio                       : 16:9 
     - Refresh rate mode                  : constant 
     - FPS Color space                    : YUV 
     - Chroma subsampling                 : 4:2:0 
     - Bit depth                          : 8 bits 
     - Scantyp                            : progressiv 
     - Codec configuration box            : avcC
```

If the movie has sound, the Audio is

```
   - ID                                       : 2
   - Format                                   : AAC LC
   - Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
   - Codec-ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
   - Bitraten-Mode                            : constant
```

Individual movie info:

```
 - Movie 1 Video 
   
     - Duration                           : 5s 900 ms
     - Bitrate                            : 1 653 kb/s 
     - Width                              : 960 Pixel
     - Height                             : 540 Pixel 
     - Image refresh rate                 : 30,000 FPS 
     - Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                 : 0.106
     - Stream-Size                        : 1,16 MiB (68%)
 - Movie 2 Video 
   
     - Duration                           : 2s 102 ms 
     - Bitrate                            : 934 kb/s 
     - Width                              : 1 280 Pixel
     - Height                             : 720 Pixel 
     - Image refresh rate                 : 29,970 (29970/1000) 
     - Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                 : 0.034
     - Stream-Size                        : 240 KiB (100%)
 - Movie 3 Video 
   
     - Duration                           : 2s 536 ms 
     - Bitrate                            : 3 931 kb/s 
     - Width                              : 1 280 Pixel
     - Height                             : 720 Pixel 
     - Image refresh rate                 : 29,970 (29970/1000) 
     - Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                 : 0.142
     - Stream-Size                        : 1,19 MiB (97%)

 - Movie 4 Video 
   
     - Duration                           : 2s 536 ms 
     - Bitrate                            : 3 931 kb/s 
     - Width                              : 1 280 Pixel
     - Height                             : 720 Pixel 
     - Image refresh rate                 : 29,970 (29970/1000) 
     - Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                 : 0.142
     - Stream-Size                        : 1,19 MiB (97%)
```

Since the flaky behaviour suggests maybe a race condition issue, please find following the method that controls showing movies in a MediaView:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param exercise, the object that encapsulates all information about a single training activity, that shall be displayed now
 * @param breakBetweenExercisesInSec, seconds to pause before the next exercise should be shown
 * @param exercises, list of remaining training exercises
 */
protected void runMovieExercise(Exercise exercise, int breakBetweenExercisesInSec, List<Exercise> exercises) {

    sets = reps = 0;                                                                                // Initialize for every new exercise
    showIntro = exercise.isShowIntro();
    setLabel.setText(Integer.toString(sets + 1) + " / " + exercise.getNumOfSets());
    repLabel.setText(Integer.toString(reps + 1) + " / " + exercise.getRepsPerSet());

    URL urlMediaLocation = getMediaLocation(exercise);
    if(urlMediaLocation == null) {
        System.err.println("Cannot show exercise: " + exercise.getMediaFilePath());
        runSession(exercises, breakBetweenExercisesInSec);                                          // Continue with next exercise
    }
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        exerciseLabel.setText(exercise.getName());
    });

    media = new Media(urlMediaLocation.toString());
    player = new MediaPlayer(media);                                                                // Every file needs a new dedicated MediaPlayer object according to API
    player.setVolume(0);                                                                            // TODO save and restore volume setting
    mediaView.setMediaPlayer(player);

    player.setOnError(() -> {
        MediaException exc = player.getError();
        LOGGER.fine("An error occurred: "  + exc.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOGGER.fine(urlMediaLocation.toExternalForm());
        exc.printStackTrace(System.err);
        ButtonType result = MessageBox.showMessageDialog(AlertType.ERROR, "Cannot show media", 
                "Couldn't open the movie file: " + exercise.getMediaFilePath() + ".\nRetry loading the media file?", 
                mediaPane.getScene().getWindow(), ButtonType.NO, ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.NO);
        if (ButtonType.NO.equals(result)) {
            runSession(exercises, breakBetweenExercisesInSec);                                      // Continue with next exercise
        } else {                
            runMovieExercise(exercise, breakBetweenExercisesInSec, exercises);                      // Retry
        }
    });


    player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {

        LOGGER.fine("setOnEndOfMedia started");

        if(showIntro) {
            reps--;
            ButtonType result = MessageBox.showMessageDialog(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Replay the introduction?", 
                    "You may want to repeat the introduction.", 
                    mediaPane.getScene().getWindow(), ButtonType.NO, ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
            if (ButtonType.NO.equals(result)) {
                showIntro = false;
            }
        }

        reps++;
        if((reps != 0) && (reps % exercise.getRepsPerSet() == 0)) {
            sets++;
            if(sets == exercise.getNumOfSets())  {                  // start the next exercise
                player.dispose();
                if(exercises.size() > 0) {
                    pause(breakBetweenExercisesInSec, "Exercise completed !");
                    LOGGER.fine("starting next exercise");
                    runSession(exercises, breakBetweenExercisesInSec);
                    return;
                } else {
                    pause(5, "YOU MADE IT !!");
                    startStopContinueButton.setText("Start");
                    setLabel.setText("");
                    repLabel.setText("");
                    startStopContinueButton.setDisable(true);
                    exerciseTable.setItems(null);
                    return;
                }
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                setLabel.setText(Integer.toString(sets + 1) + " / " + exercise.getNumOfSets());
            });
            pause(exercise.getBreakBetweenSetsInSecs(), "Set completed !");
            reps = 0;
        }
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            repLabel.setText(Integer.toString(reps + 1) + " / " + exercise.getRepsPerSet());
        });

        player.setRate(exercise.getSpeed(reps));
        player.seek(Duration.ZERO);
        player.setAutoPlay(true);
    });


    volumeSlider.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(player.volumeProperty());
    speedSlider.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(player.rateProperty());

    if(showIntro) {
        MessageBox.showMessageDialog(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Introduction", 
                "This exercise will now be shown to you for introductional purposes", 
                mediaPane.getScene().getWindow(), ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.YES);
    }

    player.setRate(exercise.getSpeed(reps));
    player.setAutoPlay(true);
}

protected URL getMediaLocation(Exercise exercise) {

    URL mediaLocationURL = null;
    File mediaLocationFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".sifuSays/exercises/" + exercise.getMediaFilePath());

    try {
        mediaLocationURL = mediaLocationFile.toURI().toURL();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot show exercise: " + mediaLocationFile.getAbsolutePath());
        mediaLocationURL = null;
    }
    return mediaLocationURL;
}
```

As you can see, in player.setOnError() the code allows to re-try opening the file, which does work. So a typical run starts the first movie without problem. For movie 2 it needs 1 re-try, movie 3 needed 7 re-trys, and movie 4 needed 3 re-trys. But I also have runs where the application needed to re-try the first movie and all others were fine. So technically each movie is "showable".

Is there something I am missing or what am I do wrong?

Should you need more code, let me know and I am happy to setup a github project to download the entire application - however, for legal reasons I cannot upload the movies, which is maybe the interesting part?!

Comment: Why do you call `Platform.runLater`?

Comment: Provide a [mcve].  *Minimal* code that replicates the issue through copy and paste with no change or addition that uses a publicly hosted media file via http.

Comment: Ensure you are using a [JavaFX version](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics) that is not early access (has `ea` in the version number).

Comment: I ran Platform.runLater since the changes of the textfields otherwise are not shown or delayed.

Comment: JavaFX: 19+11 as stated in the first sentence is no early access to my knowledge but an official release (https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/openjfx-19-release-notes/)

Comment: "I ran Platform.runLater since the changes of the textfields otherwise are not shown or delayed" -> that sounds like a problem in itself. Probably you have concurrency errors, perhaps other errors as well.

Comment: I thought the + versions were all early access, but I guess the + number is related to the build (early access will have `ea` in the version).  I ran a version check of javafx system properties on the `19` release and it returned `javafx.version` of 19, and `javafx.runtime.version` of `19+11`.  So `19+11` is the released build of the javafx runtime for the javafx `19` (not early access) release.